# How does a Rabbitmq Topic Subscriber work in a clustered application server to recieve messages?

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, cluster-computing, load-balancing, spring-amqp

I have a Rabbit Topic with multiple (say 2)subscribers which is running in a load balanced application server cluster ( say 3 ) .

So will the message will get delivered to all (2 X 3 ) subscribers of all listeners in a clustered environment  or only 2 listeners ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a "topic" in rabbitmq (amqp).

The closest thing to a JMS topic for your scenario is a `fanout` exchange with 2 queues bound to it. Each queue gets a reference to a message sent to the exchange so both consumers (one per queue) gets a copy of the message.

If you have multiple consumers (e.g. 3) on each queue, the messages in that queue are distributed round-robin fashion to those consumers. Only one consumer per queue gets a message.